# Is it possible to create a CMS workspace using API or with Metadata deploy?

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, metadata, tooling-api, mdapi

I'm trying to see if we can create a CMS workspace by using Metadata API or any other way programatically, instead of creating it through the UI as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cms_cmsworkspace-create.htm&type=5).

Also if I create a CMS workspace in an org, can I retrieve it using sfdx mdapi retrieve command? If possible, what are the types to mention in package.xml to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no public API exposed to retrieve the CMS Workspace and it is limited to UI. There is no Salesforce documentation as well that confirms API support.

**UPDATE as of May 2022**

We have a public exposed API to retrieve a CMS Workspace.
`/connect/cms/spaces/{space_id}`
This is currently in Beta version. See the Summer'22 documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_cms_space.htm)

Comment: Is this still not supported? Is there any other way to create CMS workspace than manually using UI?

Comment: @MP Please my see updated answer.

Comment: @SwethaMaddali, your update shows how to get a space not how to create it